# Get URI image from cache image file

Tags: android, image, android-listview, universal-image-loader

I have implemented search and custom suggestions in my app.
I try now to add an image next to the text of the suggestion. I am using the SearchManager class, and I populate the data to put in the suggestion's dropdown from my database, using a cursor.

I understand that what I have to add in the rows of my cursor for the columns identified by `SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1` are (as stated in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1):

1. content (SCHEME_CONTENT)
2. android.resource (SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
3. file (SCHEME_FILE)

What I have tried so far is the following:

```
private void generateSuggestionsCursor(MatrixCursor cursor, Cursor userCursor) {
            long id = cursor.getCount();

            userCursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!userCursor.isAfterLast()) {
                String userName = userCursor.getString("username");
                String uriImage = userCursor.getString("urlImage");
                File imageAsNeeded = ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache().get(uriImage);
                Uri urlAsNeeded = Uri.parse(imageAsNeeded.toString());
                cursor.newRow().add(id).add(userName).add(urlAsNeeded).add(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH).add(userName);
                userCursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
```

The problem is that I don't have the images I want to display in my dropdown locally.
I'm loading them from an URL, using [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

I have also tried to use the cached version of the pictures but the URI is always of the following form:

```
/data/data/com.app.appname/cache/1216470680
```

I have tried to prepend `file:// or content://` but without any success.

Is there anyway to achieve what I want?

[image: Suggestion dropdown - Droids should be replaced by a specific image]

Comment: Do you have to fetch the images online or can you predownload them and store them as a resource?

Comment: Ideally, it would be the best to load the picture from the url, so online. The thind is that Universal image loader makes you able to do this, but you need to specify in which imageview you wanna display your picture once loaded. In my case, I cannot access the image view (afaik)

Comment: What is it exactly that you want?  To know how to cache them in your app?

Comment: No, Universal Loader is already caching them. I need to transform the path it gave to me when I ask for it to something compatible with the File/Content scheme (file:// or content://)

Comment: Ok, I think this is outside my scope.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put them in the resources, do so:

Ideally, you need four sizes but you can get by with just the drawable-hdpi size.  To load it, do this:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable (R.drawable.my_id);
```